# How can I show image set in android java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add an image into my app with java so I googled how to do this and seen I had to add

```
Context mContext;
Drawable myImage = mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
```

(That was all of the code they said I had to add) But when I run it I don't see my image I set to it. So how I would  be able to show the image I set to it?

Comment: You set the drawable to an ImageView? Maybe you should go with some complete Tutorials like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/)

Comment: do you add `imgView.setImageDrawable(myImage);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a image to be displayed, you need to give a view for that . ie - ImageView

1. Add a ImageView in your main-layout.
2. Initialize that ImageView in the on create of your activity like

   `ImageView appImage = findViewById(R.id.your_image_View_id);`

3.Then set an image to the image view like

`appImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just initialize the imageview from layout like below,

```
ImageView appImage = findViewById(R.id.your_image_View_id);
appImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_downarrow));
```

With new android API 22 getResources().getDrawable() is now deprecated. So now the best approach is to use only getDrawable() is using `ContextCompat`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

Step1: In your main_layout.xml, add an `<ImageView ...` tag give an id, let's say id is "imageView"

Step2: In your MainActivity.class onCreate() method, Initialize that ImageView as:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

then,

Step3: assign your drawable as:

```
im.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.your_image_drawable));
```

If you are using a fragment, use:

```
im.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.your_image_drawable));
```

Hope it helps. Please update if it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView appImage = findViewById(R.id.your_image_View_id);
```

In activity simply use setImageResource

```
appImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_avatar);
```